# Move some fileds of array

Tags: php, arrays

i am working with rest api in php and with use of mysql query ,I am getting following array (1 and 2 are cat_ids),
I just want to move cat_id and cat_image outside of array,I mean i want to show first cat_id with cat_name and inside this i want to get all selfie images with user ids and then second cat_name and cat id and inside this i want to get all selfie images and user id and so on

Here is my code.

```
foreach($userArr as $k=>$v){
$userCatArr[$v['cat_id']][] = $v; //add node
        unset($userCatArr[$v['cat_id']]['cat_id']); //unset doubles
    }
    $userArr = $userCatArr; unset($userCatArr);
        print_R($userArr);
```

And i am getting following result

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 16
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 4
                    [cat_image] => abcd.jpg
                    [selfie_image] => abc.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 4
                    [cat_image] => xyze.jpg
                    [selfie_image] => xyz.jpg
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 16
                    [cat_id] => 2
                    [user_id] => 4
                    [cat_image] => abcdee.jpg
                    [selfie_image] => abc.jpg
                )
       )
```

But i want to change result like following array

```
Array
(
    [cat_id] => 1
    [cat_image] => abc.jpg
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 4
                    [selfie_image] => abc.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 4
                    [selfie_image] => xyz.jpg
                )

        )

    [cat_id] => 2
    [cat_image] => xyz.jpg
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 4
                    [selfie_image] => abc.jpg
                )
       )
```

Comment: You've asked already - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664860/make-array-inside-array-in-php

Comment: Is cat_image a string or array. It seems as it's both. Also I agree with the comments on the previous question, not possible.